# Java server not sending consecutive messages until message is received

Tags: java

I have two classes that work fine if the server sends a message and the client replies before the server sends another one. For example, the server says "Hello" and the client responds with "Hi". But if the server were to send "Hello" and then "How are you?", the second message would not be sent until the client sends a message. Can I change this to allow multiple messages to be sent without a response first?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
   ServerSocket newServer;
   Socket newSocket;
   DataInputStream newInputStream;
   DataOutputStream newOutputStream;
   BufferedReader newReader;

   public Server () {
      try {
         this.newServer = new ServerSocket(4444);
         this.newSocket = newServer.accept();
         this.newInputStream = new DataInputStream(newSocket.getInputStream());
         this.newOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(newSocket.getOutputStream());
         this.newReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }

   public void handleMessages () {
      try {
         String MessageReceived = "";
         String MessageSent;
         while (!MessageReceived.equals("End Connection")) {
            MessageReceived = newInputStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Client says: " + MessageReceived);
            MessageSent = newReader.readLine();
            newOutputStream.writeUTF(MessageSent + "\n");
            newOutputStream.flush();
         }
         newInputStream.close();
         newOutputStream.close();
         newSocket.close();
         newServer.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Server newServer = new Server ();
      newServer.handleMessages();
   }
}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
   Socket newSocket;
   DataInputStream newInputStream;
   DataOutputStream newOutputStream;
   BufferedReader newReader;

   public Client () {
      try {
         newSocket = new Socket ("localhost", 4444);
         newInputStream = new DataInputStream(newSocket.getInputStream());
         newOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(newSocket.getOutputStream());
         newReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }
   public void handleMessages () {
      try {
         String MessageReceived;
         String MessageSent = "";
         while (!MessageSent.equals("End Connection")) {
            if (newInputStream.available() > 0) {
               MessageReceived = newInputStream.readUTF();
               System.out.println("Server says: " + MessageReceived);
            }
            if (newReader.ready()) {
               MessageSent = newReader.readLine();
               newOutputStream.writeUTF(MessageSent + "\n");
               newOutputStream.flush();
            }
         }
         newInputStream.close();
         newOutputStream.close();
         newSocket.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Client newClient = new Client ();
      newClient.handleMessages();
   }
}
```

Comment: You need [multi-threading](https://gist.github.com/declank/8fce5a02e4b6bb572e7a)